# Java generics: matching the type of a parameter

Tags: java, generics, types, parameters

How would I modify this so the resulting Collection (newNodes) is the same type as the incoming one (nodes)?

```
public void setNodes(Collection<NodeInfo> nodes) {
    Collection<NodeInfo> newNodes = new TreeSet<NodeInfo>();
    for (NodeInfo ni: nodes) {
        newNodes.add(ni.clone());
    }
}
```

I suspect it's something like...

```
public void setNodes(<T extends Collection<NodeInfo>> nodes) {
    Collection<NodeInfo> newNodes = new T<NodeInfo>()
```

Is this possible?

Comment: It's not possible, and probably not desirable anyway. BTW, your example doesn't do anything useful: it fills up a local TreeSet and discards it immediately.

Comment: I should have added some ellipses or a description... This method currently takes in a Collection<NodeInfo>, makes a deep copy, and sets the local member to the copy in one fell, synchronized swoop. There is more processing after the for loop but before the assignment, which I left out, sorry for the misrepresentation.

Answer (score 2):

Close, but no cigar. If I understand what you want to do, your method should look like:

```
public <T extends NodeInfo> void setNodes(Collection<T> nodes) {
    Collection<T> newNodes = new TreeSet<T>();
    for(T t : nodes) {
        newNodes.add(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: you could write <T> instead of <T extends Object>. Both mean the same.

Comment: Whoops -- that was supposed to be a `NodeInfo` in reference to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it's not possible as you've written it in Java. If you need this effect, you've got a few choices:

If you're trying to optimize for a particular kind of collection, you can use an `instanceof` check to detect it. (For instance the Guava libraries often do this to detect immutable collections and handle them specially.)

If you really just need one collection to populate, you can ask the caller to provide you one.

```
public <C extends Collection<NodeInfo>> void setNodes(C nodes, C newNodes) {
  for (NodeInfo ni : nodes) {
    newNodes.add(ni);
  }
}
```

If you need the ability to make an arbitrary number of these collections on demand, then you can define a factory interface and make the caller provide an instance of it:

```
interface Factory<C extends Collection<NodeInfo>> {
  C newCollection();
}

public <C extends Collection<NodeInfo>> void setNodes(C nodes, Factory<C> factory) {
  C newNodes = factory.newCollection();
  for (NodeInfo ni : nodes) {
    newNodes.add(ni);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot do `new T` in Java: Since generics are implemented in Java via type erasure, the type information that is provided by a type parameter is only statically usable information, i.e. no longer available at runtime.  Hence Java does not permit generic creation of objects (cf. [Angelika Lange's Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#How%20do%20I%20generically%20create%20objects%20and%20arrays?)).

Alternatively, you could use:

- a type token, i.e. use a `Class<T>` object as parameter to make the type available at runtime
- use the signature `void setNodes(Collection<NodeInfo> nodes, Collection<NodeInfo> newNodes)` if you are able to create the suitable Collection elsewhere
- use a standard Collection implementation if one is suitable, e.g. `ArrayList<NodeInfo>`
- deep clone `nodes`, e.g. using [The Cloning Library](http://code.google.com/p/cloning/):

  Cloner cloner=new Cloner();

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") `Collection<NodeInfo> newNodes = cloner.deepClone(nodes);`

Comment: my code sample doesn't display correctly. how do I write this in stackoverflow immediately after an enumeration?

Answer (score 0):

Note that many of the `Collection` implementations in the JDK implement `Cloneable` themselves. One "best effort" approach might be like this:

```
public Collection<NodeInfo> setNodes(Collection<NodeInfo> nodes) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    Collection<NodeInfo) newNodes;

    if (nodes instanceof Cloneable) 
        newNodes = (Collection<NodeInfo>) newNodes.clone();
    else
        // Fallback in case we have a non-cloneable collection
        newNodes = new TreeSet<NodeInfo>();

    newNodes.clear();
    for (NodeInfo ni: nodes) {
        newNodes.add(ni.clone());
    }
    return newNodes;
}
```

This returns the same kind of collection for many inputs, but will fall back to returning a `TreeSet` as a default if it can't do any better.